# How do I upload a file using protractor

Tags: file-upload, protractor

I'm writing a protractor script that need to upload a JPEG image. I could click on the upload button which opens up a windows file selector. But, then I need to write the path to a file in that File Selector dialog using protractor.

But, i have no idea how it works. I tried just typing the path using `sendKeys` and it doesn't work so far.

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314337/4711957) it may help you.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try my answer in "[How can I control the windows File Selector using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153628/how-can-i-control-the-windows-file-selector-using-protractor/37156380#37156380)".

If you need a quick solution try the following solution:

```
// set file detector
var remote = require('../../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());


var fileToUpload = '../sample.txt';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

// Unhide file input
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';  arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());

fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);

// take a breath 
browser.driver.sleep(100);

// click upload button
element(by.css('button[data-ng-click="uploadFile(file)"]')).click(); // does post request
```

Comment: Quick and simple. Thanks Quality Products. :)

Comment: this is not working with android hybrid application testing (protractor+appium). my file input <input type="file" id="fileLabtest" style="display:none"> selector element(by.css('[id="fileLabtest"]')).sendKeys('/home/myPC/Pictures/fingerpointing.jpg');

Comment: The sleep + executeScript fixed an issue I had where randomly, the file was not uploaded.

Now the test succeeds everytime.

Comment: file upload code works for me but when I have my project folder in any other driver other then Desktop, so how can I get my file to be picked from a folder which is on Desktop? my code is "var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    var input = element(by.css('input[type=file]'));
    input.sendKeys(absolutePath);"

Comment: This worked for me. I struggled for a while using my own version of the browser.executeScript() part. If you read this - follow it to the letter before modifying for your own code

Answer (score 1):

```
        [settingsEditProfile_page.settingsEditProfile_UploadImageButton()][1].isDisplayed().then(function () {
                  helperUtil.addStep("User redirected to Edit Profile page");            settingsEditProfile_page.settingsEditProfile_UploadImageButton().sendKeys(absolutePath).then(function () {
                  helperUtil.addStep("User clicked on upload button and uploaded new image");
                  browser.driver.sleep(3000);

  settingsEditProfile_page.settingsEditProfile_Save().click().then(function () {
         helperUtil.addStep("User clicked on SAVE button");
                                });
                              });
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 uploadFile: async (locator, filepath) => {
  absolutePath = path.resolve(filepath);
  click(locator);
  element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
  await sleep(10000, "wait to close window");
  await closePopup();
},
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.